# How to display a JSON object starting from a specific index?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc

I have this example as a json object

```
var obj = [{name: "ana", gender: "woman"}, {name: "ben", gender: "man"}, 
           {name: "andrew", gender: "man"}, {name: "jake", gender: "man"}]
```

I want to display the list starting from the 2nd index until the last index of the json object. Just like a Take() from ASP.NET

I have this code to achieve it. But is there other way, like a better solution than this code to make the process more lighter? Thank you so much.

Here's my code:

```
 var obj = [{name: "ana", gender: "woman"}, {name: "ben", gender: "man"}, 
           {name: "andrew", gender: "man"}, {name: "jake", gender: "man"}];

   $scope.run = function () {
   var display = {};        
   var startingIndex = 1;        
   for(var i = 0;i >= startingIndex;i++){
   display.push(obj[i]);
   }
    alert(JSON.stringify(display));
  }
```

Comment: this doesn't look like a valid object.....

Comment: @Claies thanks for pointing it out! Will edit my question.

Comment: @Claies +1 for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method.

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array
>   into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included).
>   The original array will not be modified.

```js
var obj = [{name: "ana", gender: "woman"}, {name: "ben", gender: "man"}, 
           {name: "andrew", gender: "man"}, {name: "jake", gender: "man"}];
obj=obj.slice(2);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: this isn't right;  the original question had an object with a series of arrays, you changed it to an array of objects.  even though it doesn't look like their structure is correct, and this is probably what they actually meant to show, you should clarify, rather than just change the structure completely.

Comment: it's worth noting I didn't down vote the answer, someone else did; I just wanted to clarify this point and ensure that the code is actually valid and that the problem the OP was having wasn't actually related to their misuse of objects/arrays.

Comment: Guys I already edited my code. Sorry for the mistake. Thank you guys.

Comment: Plus one for this answer. Thank you!